# git pull/push from/to github in VPN does not work

Tags: networking, git, vpn, proxy, github

I am having problems when pulling commits from my github repository from private network (proxy, connected to it with VPN). no_proxy var in env did not help.

```
git pull --rebase
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the repository is not reachable when you're connected to that VPN. Try pinging it, and inspect the output.

You can also try running Linux command:

```
$traceroute <your-repo-hostname>
```

with and without a VPN connection to inspect it as well.

Then I suggest you check the VPN settings. Most likely the error was made there.

This [link](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting-reaching-systems-over-the-vpn-tunnel/) should be helpful to do so.

Comment: I can actually reach my repo (github.com) via browser, i also pinged it. I just do not reach the port 22 while pulling commits. I tried, as said, no_proxy for my git to surpass the Proxy. It did not help. VPN settings are ok.

Comment: Have you checked this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out ?

Comment: i have tried it as suggested with configs (i.e. https, 443 etc.) but no help. <br/> `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myuserName/repo.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 1080: Timed out <br/>
$ ssh -T git@github.com
ssh: connect to host github.com port 443: Connection timed out
`

Comment: Did you tried rebooting your OS, maybe some weird VPN interfaces problem, you can also try listing your iptables rules.
If you're trying this through ssh then you don't need https, just do git command git@repowhatever.git

Comment: @Bohdan that worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (couldn't connect with `ssh -T git@github.com`). The issue resolved itself when I changed my DNS server (to CloudFlare). Not sure how DNS could cause this since, like you, I could connect via my browser and ping, but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by forcing SSH to use IPv4 instead of IPv6.

Add this to your `.ssh/config` file

```
AddressFamily inet
```

Taking from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671706/configure-git-to-use-ipv4-instead-of-ipv6-by-default